# How to query Google Calendar event's fate?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm looking for a way programmatically find out who deleted an event on a shared Google Calendar. I have a calendar owned by an individual which is shared with their assistants who have read/write access, recently events have disappeared and we're not sure who or what deleted them.

We've previously just contacted Google (we're an Apps customer) and provided them with an eid of an event and they would get back to us the username of the person who deleted the event and which software they were using (i.e. using pocketinformant on iPad).

So instead of bothering Google each time, I'm wondering if there is a way to access this data through their APIs. We make good use of the Calendar API (v3) but I don't see any options to query a deleted event directly. I can see a cancelled/deleted event with events.list but if I query the event directly (events.get) I get a 404.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call the Events.List method for the particular calendarID. Once you have all the events you can use a LINQ or LAMBDA function on the list to find your particular event.

```
 var request = service.Events.List(calendarId);
 request.ShowDeleted = true;
 var result = request.Fetch().Items;

 var calendarEvents = result.Where(c ==> c.EventID).ToList();
```